# Flask - Detect when a POST parameter is not present

Tags: python-3.x, flask, post, request

An endpoint of my server is triggered like this:

```
curl --header "Content-Type: application/json" --request POST --data '{"selected_object":"6qzEgPnzxZWW8MaSYwCquP.txt", "action": 0}' 0.0.0.0:5000/do_stuff
```

When the `action` parameter is given, it is parsed, and an operation is performed, depending on its value.

This is how it's parsed:

```
@app.route("/do_stuff", methods=["POST"])
def do_it():
    request_contents = request.get_json()
    what_action = request_contents.get("action")
```

I want to be able to make the server work, even when this is not available in the POST request.

How do i detect if the item `action` is available in the POST request?

Comment: `get()` does not raise a `KeyError`, the code execution won't be interrupted. Your `what_action` will be `None`. If you need another default value instead, pass it to `get("action", your_default_value)`.

Answer (score 0):

`Request.get_json()` will return a `dict`. Just check if 'action' is in the `dict`.

```py
action_exists = "action" in request_contents
```